# Haskell is getting deadlocked in a situation it (in theory) shouldn't be

Tags: haskell, networking

The following yields a deadlock error message (*** Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation). I've thought it through step by step, and I don't see the issue.

- On the main thread, a MVar is created, and given to producer, running on a new thread
- producer starts, and blocks at listenOn, waiting for a connection
- The main thread continues into the loop, and blocks, waiting for the MVar to receive something
- Once producer gets a connection, it continues into it's loop, and after receiving something from the socket, puts it into the MVar

Meaning (as far as I understand it), it should end up with producer putting something in the MVar, and main waiting to receive something.

If it's getting stuck because listenOn doesn't connect immediately, how can I get around this? The MVar needs to be created in main, and before producer is forked so it can be passed in.

```
import Control.Concurrent

import Network
import Network.Socket

import System.IO

getSockInfo :: Socket -> IO String
getSockInfo s = do
        info <- getPeerName s
        return $ case info of
            (SockAddrInet port addr) -> "Addr/Port: " ++ (show addr) ++ " / " ++ (show port)
            (SockAddrInet6 port flow addr scope) ->
                "Addr/Port: " ++ (show addr) ++ " / " ++ (show port) ++ "Flow/Scope: " ++ (show flow) ++ " / " ++ (show scope)

producer :: MVar String -> IO ()
producer m = do
    s <- listenOn (PortNumber 5555)
    putStrLn "Listening..."
    info <- getSockInfo s
    putStrLn $ "Connected to " ++ info
    h <- socketToHandle s ReadMode
    loop h m
    where loop h m = do
        message <- hGetLine h
        putMVar m message
        loop h m

main :: IO ()
main = do
    withSocketsDo $ do
        m <- newEmptyMVar
        prod <- forkIO $ producer m
        loop m
        where loop m = do
            n <- takeMVar m
            print n
            loop m
```

Comment: Are you building with -threaded?

Comment: @Ganesh No. Doesn't that only change the behavior of sendTo/receiveFrom?

Comment: Not sure, but it's the first thing I check when I have a concurrency problem. Doesn't seem to make a difference in this case though.

Comment: When I try this I get errors from `getPeerName` first before the blocked indefinitely exception. Since those errors would kill the thread that would `putMVar`, it's not surprising that the main thread is then considered to be deadlocked. Do you also get those initial errors? I've tried on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: From `getPeerName`, not `getPeerInfo`? `getPeerInfo` may throw a pattern matching error due to my module not having one of the Linux constructors that `getPeerName` returns.

Comment: `getPeerName`, yes: `failed (Socket is not connected (WSAENOTCONN))` on Windows, and `invalid argument (Transport endpoint is not connected)` on Linux.

Comment: It shouldn't have been called until listenOn receives a connection though (which, unless you connected to it via a client, should never have happened). But no, I don't get that. It sits at Listening for a sec, then gives the error.

Comment: What does it do if you remove the info part?

Comment: Then I get an error from hGetLine: `invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)`.  If I replace the call to `socketToHandle` with a call to `accept` then it seems to wait fine.

Comment: Whoops. Do I have a accept the connection after listenOn returns a socket? I thought my simple chat program only used accept on the client, and listenOn on the server side. Accept's return also does the job of getPeerInfo.

Comment: @Ganesh Wow, this is embarrassing. It seems to be because I never called accept. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listenOn` returns immediately but doesn't give you a connected socket, so attempts to use it or read from it fail. I'm not sure why you aren't seeing an error message to indicate that, since I do when I run your code. In any case the listening thread is probably dying at that point, which leaves the main thread deadlocked as nothing can write to the MVar.

Using `accept` after `listenOn` to wait for a remote connection should fix this.

Comment: Thank you sir. I don't understand why I'm getting a deadlocking error instead of a connection error though. You'd think it would realize the connection problem before the mvar one (unless that's an artifact of laziness. You'd think it would be consistent across system though)

Comment: Probably the thread with `listenOn` dies with an exception, but if you don't propagate that exception to the main thread you'll never see it. I suggest using the `async` package to create your threads. It will handle things like exception safety and propagating exceptions for you.

Comment: I did see the exception printed on the console when I ran the code in the question, but perhaps the OP is using a different compiler or similar.